# Named groups for query-replace-regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, query-replace

I'd like to define a function to do a `query-replace-regexp` with a pattern I often use. When not using capture groups, it works:

```
(defun my-replace ()
    (interactive)
    (query-replace-regexp "[[:nonascii:][:ascii:]]*xxx" "replacedText" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use capture groups -- neither '\(\)' nor '()' works:

```
(defun my-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (query-replace-regexp "([[:nonascii:][:ascii:]]*)xxx" "\1replacedText" nil (point-min) (point-max)))


(defun my-replace ()
    (interactive)
    (query-replace-regexp "\([[:nonascii:][:ascii:]]*\)xxx" "\1replacedText" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

But when invoked with M-x `query-replace-regexp`, `\([[:nonascii:][:ascii:]]*\)xxx` would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp string literals, backslash is an escape character.  To express a single literal backslash character, as required by many regular expression constructs, you need two backslashes, eg:

```
"\\([[:nonascii:][:ascii:]]*\\)xxx"
```

You don't need the extra backslashes when you run `query-replace-regexp` interactively because you're not entering a string literal, ie, an Emacs Lisp language construct; you're entering the characters of the regexp directly.

Try hitting <kbd>M-:</kbd> (`eval-expression`) and entering this expression:

```
"\(foo\)"
```

You'll see:

```
"(foo)"
```

...indicating that an escaped parenthesis in a string literal is the same as an unescaped parenthesis.  So the regular expression engine was seeing parentheses without a preceding backslash, which match only themselves; they weren't starting or ending a capturing group as you expected.

Comment: That fixed it but it seems neither `\1` or `\\1` is working as the replacement part.

Comment: Works for me with `"\\1replacedText"` as the replacement string.

Comment: Well explained, Sean. It is especially good that you mentioned why the extra backslashes are not used when interactive (not only not *needed*, but not usable, BTW).

Comment: `\\1` does work.  It was a faulty regexp that caused me to think it didn't,

Answer (score 3):

Use "\" to quote "\":

```
(defun my-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (query-replace-regexp "\\([[:nonascii:][:ascii:]]*\\)xxx" "\\1replacedText"
                        nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```